# Azure name server for Microsoft Imagine subscription

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, nameservers

I've created a wordpress blog as a Web App. It works correctly so I've bought a domain from a registrar and I would use it as primary domain of my web site.
The question is: what is the name servers to set dns rules from the domain control panel?
In the Azure Portal the DNS zone panel is unaccessible with current subscription.
I'm doing something of wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set DNS servers for the WebApp in the Azure Portal, you would need to [verify ownership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name). You need to alter the specific DNS records with the provider you bought it from.

Comment: Thank you @4c74356b41 but following the procedure, under "custom domain" (domini personalizzati in italian) I cannot view and do anything because the current plan is not enough. it is needed the premium plan. do you confirm it? thanks

Comment: no, you only need shared plan or above, as far as I recall.